# If we get some error on API (4xx or 5xx), we should be showing something on the screen

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How to handle such errors and show message on the screen?

The code is:

```html
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import ENV from 'website-my/config/environment';

const API_BASE_URL = ENV.BASE_API_URL;

export default class TasksRoute extends Route {
  model = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/tasks/self`, {
      credentials: 'include',
    });
    const allTasks = await response.json();

    return allTasks;
  };
}
```

I want to add error handling in this, How to do that?

Comment: You can catch server side errors by wrapping await codes with try/catch block.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments